# $Q$ is perfectly conditioned with respect to the 2-condition number.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonality

Show that if $Q$ is orthogonal, then:

$||Q||_2 = 1$,
  $||Q^{-1}||_2=1$,
 and $\kappa_2(Q)=1$.

---

Tell me if I'm wrong but, I'm at if $||QQ^T||_2 = ||I||_2$ then $||QQ^T||_2 = 1$

which implies that

$||Q||_2 = 1$ after that, I can assume that $||Q^T||_2 = 1$ and if $||Q|| = ||Q^T||_2 = 1$ then its condition number is 1.

But as a student, I don't know the elegant/most correct way to say what I'm thinking.